# Prove that two completions of the same metric space are isometric

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X_1,d_1),(X_2,d_2)$ two completions of the same metric space $(X,d)$.

Then exist $f:X\rightarrow X_1$ isometry so that $f(X)$ is dense in $X_1$ and $g:X\rightarrow X_2$ isometry so that $g(X)$ is dense in $X_2$.

I consider $g \circ f^{-1}: f(X)\rightarrow g(X)$. Because $f$ and $g$ are isometries then $g \circ f^{-1}$ is an isometry.

Isometry is uniformly continuous and $X_1$ is complete so $g \circ f^{-1}$ has an isometric extension $h$ to the clousure $\overline{f(X)}=X_1$.
Idem $f \circ g^{-1}$ has an isometric extension $h'$ to $\overline{g(X)}=X_2$.

So $h' \circ h: X_1 \rightarrow X_1$ is the identity on $f(X)$ and for density on $X_1$?

Comment: You're on the right lines, can you find a *unique bijective* isometry $h: X \to X$ such that $g=h \circ f$?, as a hint, given an $y \in X$, choose a Cauchy sequence $x_k \in X$ such that $f(x_k)$ converges to $y$...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a isometry is uniformly continuos, so it extends uniquely to the closure.

Comment: It's right my conclusion up?